# How can I set default options for node's JSON.stringify()?

Tags: node.js, json

I know I can run:

```
 JSON.stringify(someObject, null, 2)
```

To get indented output. But I recall reading there was a way to specify the default options for node's `JSON.stringify()` implementation, so I can so just do that and then:

```
JSON.stringify(someObject)
```

And get readable output. But I can't find mention of JSON in [node's docs](https://nodejs.org/api/). Although I know I can monkey patch JSON.stringify()...

```
global.originalJSONStringify = JSON.stringify

global.JSON.stringify = function wrappedJSONStringify(value, replacer, space = 2) {
  return global.originalJSONStringify(value, replacer, space)
}
```

And as a test:

```
var results = JSON.stringify({key: {subkey: 'value'}})
var expected = originalJSONStringify({key: {subkey: 'value'}}, null, 2)
assert.equal(results, expected)
```

But I'd rather not do that if there's better solution.

**How can I set default options for node's JSON.stringify()?**

Comment: Wrap it in your own func?

Comment: I am suggesting something like `const myjson = (x) => JSON.stringify(x, null, 2)` and using that. That's not monkey-patching. As for some kind of global settings for JSON serialization, there's nothing like that in JS.

Comment: @AlexeyZabrodsky I read your comment as 'wrap JSON.stringify() in your own JSON.stringify()' not 'wrap JSON.stringify() is your own differently named function'. I see you mean the latter. Nevertheless, my objective is exactly as the question asks: 'How can I set default options for nodes JSON.stringify()?'

Answer (score 1):

From [Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

you can do something like this

```
var obj = {
    data: 'data',

    toJSON(key){
        if(key)
            return `Now I am a nested object under key '${key}'`;

        else
            return this;
    }
};

JSON.stringify(obj);
// '{"data":"data"}'

JSON.stringify({ obj })
// '{"obj":"Now I am a nested object under key 'obj'"}'

JSON.stringify([ obj ])
// '["Now I am a nested object under key '0'"]'
```